# How to read text from printed paper, OCR or something else?

Tags: android, text, numbers, ocr

I need to read text from printed paper with my Android device, but I can't find other solution than OCR. Is there any way to scan text ? Or OCR is best? It can be text and numbers without bar-code. I need this for my school project and I am lost, please help.

Can you please send me some examples, code on github ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many OCR libraries for android. The [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)(Open Computer Vision) library, Tesseract OCR Tool by google and Aspire are some OCR libraries available.

The OpenCV library can be used both in Java and C++ code. It can also be linked to a static or dynamic using runtime application called OpenCV Manager. You can find the [documentations](http://docs.opencv.org/) and [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/df8/tutorial_root.html) here.

The Tesseract OCR Tool is an open source library maintained by google. [Tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/) is the fork of Tesseract Tools for Android. You can take a look into some tutorials available.

http://rmtheis.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/using-tesseract-tools-for-android-to-create-a-basic-ocr-app/

http://imperialsoup.com/2016/04/29/simple-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract-tutorial/

There are some OCR scanner libraries which use the above tools which makes implementing OCR easier.

[EasyOcrScannerAndroid](https://github.com/priyankvex/Easy-Ocr-Scanner-Android)

[Tess-two-Example](https://github.com/bieliaievays/Tess-two_example)